# How to change ConfigurationToBuild of MSBuild to specific project in TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild

i take this code from blow link
[MSbuild task fails because "Any CPU" solution is built out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688162/msbuild-task-fails-because-any-cpu-solution-is-built-out-of-order)

```
<Project ...>
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- We want to build the install solution after the build solution -->
  <BuildSolutionsInParallel>false</BuildSolutionsInParallel>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/Pricer/Pricer.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties></Properties>
  </SolutionToBuild>
  <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/Pricer/Pricer.Install/Pricer.Install.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties></Properties>
  </SolutionToBuild>
</ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
      <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
      <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
    </ConfigurationToBuild>
    <ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|x86">
      <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
      <PlatformToBuild>x86</PlatformToBuild>
    </ConfigurationToBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

my question is that now i want to specify

**the X86 for $(BuildProjectFolderPath)/Pricer/Pricer.sln**

and

**Any CPU for $(BuildProjectFolderPath)/Pricer/Pricer.Install/Pricer.Install.sln**

Means is there any specification or Properties i need set in SoutionToBuild

Answer (score 2):

Modify your solutions [this way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/25/solution-configurations.aspx) and change your ConfigurationToBuild to:

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Mixed Platforms">
  <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
  <PlatformToBuild>Mixed Platforms</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
```

Comment: I seen your give link early and i follow it too but same thing happen.My Binaries not generate.Something  i missing in code. But this is not give me proper output.